# Enabling quota on xfs partitions

Tags: partition, xfs, quota

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

I have installed the `quota` commandline tool from apt and found some instructions to enable quota on the root partition by appending `rootflags=uquota,gquota` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` within the file /etc/default/grub followed by `update-grub` and rebooting.

This seems to only effect my root partition as `repquota -a` gives the following output.

```
*** Report for user quotas on device /dev/sda5
Block grace time: 7days; Inode grace time: 7days
                        Block limits                File limits
User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
root      -- 2791432       0       0         176163     0     0
daemon    --      52       0       0              1     0     0
etc.
etc.
```

As i would like to check the /var (/dev/sda6) partition aswel i tried to fill in either of `,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group` or `,uquota,gquota` to /etc/fstab for /var but `mount` keeps outputting noquota:

```
(rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

Rebooting with either of those mount options leaves me with a boot error when trying to mount /var.

How can i achieve quota control on my other partitions?

Comment: What is the error when mounting /var ?  What is your fstab,  `grpjquota` looks to be typo.

Comment: Hi @JohnMahowald . Thanks for answering. No errors are present when remounting with verbose option on. The option `grpjquota` was taken from a howtoforge guide on Ubuntu 16.04. Should it be a different option? My fstab for var would look like this `/dev/sda6 /var xfs noatime,relatime,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group 0 0`

Comment: I don't see your error, I'm able to mount xfs with userquota or userjquota  all of which are reflected in mount output.  What is your boot error when trying to mount /var ?

Comment: Hi @JohnMahowald. Thanks for taking me closer to the real problem here. But trying `userquota` and reboot leaves me with emergency mode during boot. But in fact the problem seems to be the naming of the quota options. I found these two options (`,usrquota,grpquota`) that solved my problem together with a reboot. Now `repquota` show me the quota output i was looking for. If you post an answer i will accept it as you took your time to try to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the naming of the options. The correct options were `usrquota` and `grpquota`. Appending these two options to the mountpoint enabled me to watch quota statistics under my /var partition too.